# What are sets and classes in maths, and how are they related to $O()$ and $o()$ notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, asymptotics, foundations

Are there many definitions of sets and classes in mathematics, as given in [Formal definion of the notations used in measuring time complexity?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29488/formal-definion-of-the-notations-used-in-measuring-time-complexity?noredirect=1#comment59762_29488) 
And in particular, why the notation given in [Fedja's comment](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=296&t=31517&start=20) gives a class rather than a set?

#### Fedja's comment:

I have a colleague (a very fine mathematician, by the way), who insists that the way the $ o()$ and $ O()$ notation is currently used is nothing but an abuse of 
mathematical language. His argument is that $ =$ should always be an 
equivalence relation and $ \sin x = O(1)$ and $ 1 = O(1)$ imply 
neither $ O(1) = \sin x$, nor $ \sin x = 1$. Besides, the same 
symbol $ O(x)$ means a lot of different things. The formally correct approach 
to the big and little O notation, in his opinion, should be the following. Given 
a positive $ g$ defined in a punctured neighborhood of $ x_0$, denote by $ 
O_{x_0}(g)$ the class of all functions $ f$ such that the ratio $ f/g$ is 
bounded in some punctured neighbourhood of $ x_0$. This is a perfectly 
meaningful mathematical object with unique meaning. Now, instead of writing $ 
f(x) = O(g(x))$ as $ x\to x_0$, write $ f\in O_{x_0}(g)$. If you 
understand the arithmetic operations over classes of functions in the sense of 
Minkowski, i.e., $ A*B = \{f*g: f\in A,g\in B\}$ where $ *$ is any of the 
four arithmetic operations, then you can elaborate upon this idea and instead 
of writing $ 1 + \sin x = 1 + O(|x|) = 1 + o(1)$ as 
$ x\to 0$, write the formally correct $ 1 + \sin x\in 1 + 
O_0(|x|)\subset 1 + o_0(1)$. And so on, and so forth. I find his logic 
irrefutable but I do not think he has a big chance to win his crusade :)

Comment: Could you quote the content from the links directly into your question?

Comment: Abuse of notation isn't always a problem. I don't think I'd agree with saying it is 'nothing but' abuse of notation. It is still useful, even if we don't write everything the way maybe it should formally.

Comment: In this context one use the word "class" as in "equivalence class", but it is actually a set.

Comment: @Siméon Big $O$, it isn't equivalence classes. $O(\log n)$ is contained in $O(n)$. Neither is little $o$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: indeed, my comment was confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning between "class" and "set" in this particular usage.

He is correct on the right way to formalize these notations, but the shorthand is so much easier to read, and, as long as everybody knows what you mean, it is acceptable.